# I didnt get the datatable format in my page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I added a datatable for one page, but it shouldn't get the datatable format

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="example3" id="example1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example3').DataTable();
    alert('1234567890');

  } );
</script>
```

I got an error like this, I checked both the class and id class 
they both come from the database. If I remove the data I also don't get the values.

TypeError: c is undefined

```
    ...ldren("th, td").each(function(a,b){var c=o.aoColumns[a];if(c.mData===a){var d=s(...
```

Please let me know where the mistake is, because the same code used in other projects works.

Comment: We need more information about your code, as it appears that what you have works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zdrpd2fs/

Comment: Try added <thead> tag with rows titles

Answer (score 0):

Your table has to have correct structure, see [Installation - HTML](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).

```
<table class="example3" id="example1">
   <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```